# Cant Bind JSON data to View in Angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I Have called a API and returned data successfully.
But with that JSON data, I cant bind with the view.
Below is the HTML Template

```
<StackLayout>            
        <Label [text]="users.BookingReferenceID"> </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

This is my app.component.ts

```
this._dataService.Search(id)            
            .subscribe((data) => this.users = JSON.stringify(data),
             error => console.log(error),
             () => {(
                   console.log('Data Retrieved successfully' + this.users))   
             });
```

This is the data returned from the api

```
{"Collection":  
 [{"IsIndexData":false,
"DocumentNumber":"2300000002018",
"BookingReferenceID":"CID0EX",
"IssuingDate":"2016-11-04T00:00:00",
"Errors":null,"Information":null,
"Warnings":null}],
"Errors":null,
"Information":null,
"Warnings":null}
```

Always I will get undefined in the view..Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `JSON.stringify`ing the data which means that you are turning your `data` object into a string and inside the html you are trying to select the `string`s field like an `object`.

Remove the `JSON.stringify` from data.

Leave it like this:

```
.subscribe((data) => this.users = data,
```

And your html should be something like:

```
<StackLayout>            
        <Label [text]="users?.Collection[0].BookingReferenceID"> </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried this...But still im getting this exception

Comment: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:3:19 caused by: Cannot read property 'BookingReferenceID' of undefined

Comment: @RajivKrishnaa What does `.subscribe((data) => console.log(data)` logs?

Comment: In my log, it displays [object Object]

Comment: @RajivKrishnaa Glad I could help :)