# Binding data [object object] in angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

I got data like this in my console from my API:

```
[
    {
        id:"123",
        name:"asd",
        address:"st.dddss",
        status:1
    }
]
```

I call it using `ngFor` and I got this error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

But that still works and data is showing. This is my code:

```
this._service
    .getHotelbyId(this.id)
    .subscribe(hotel =>
        {
          this.Hotels = hotel
          console.log(this.Hotels);
        },
        error =>
        {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

And I call it like this using `*ngFor`

```
*ngFor="let z of Hotels

{{z.name}} , {{z.address}}
```

How to solve that error message?

Comment: `console.log(this.Hotels` - what is the output?

Comment: i got this [{id:"123",name:"asd",address:"st.dddss",status:1}]

Comment: {{ Hotels | json }} - try this and what's the output.?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is because you assigned the JSON string response you obtained from your api to `this.Hotels`.

You need to parse the JSON string as your Javascript object. Try this.

```
this.Hotels = JSON.parse(hotel)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved just remove ngFor and use index of array like this `Hotels[0].name`
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315078/cant-bind-json-data-to-view-in-angular2-nativescript)